# Life span of a Java enum instance

Tags: java, enums

I understand there is one single instance per predefined constant of an enum type. Is that even right? Now, suppose there is an instance variable called `value` of the enum, and suppose `ONE` is a predefined constant. If `value` is modified for (the) instance of `ONE` then this affects all variables referring to `ONE`. But what happens to the value of `value` when the garbage collector gets rid of all instances of the enum? Do they ever get thrown away even?

*Example*

Here is a simple example where there are two variables `A` and `B`, both referring to `ONE`. The value of `value` is negated before `B` is used for the first time. If the garbage collector had gotten rid of the instance of `ONE` before the line `Number B = Number.ONE;`, then the value of `value` would have been "reset" back to 1, I presume. Is this correct?

**The enum:**

```
public enum Number
{
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3); 

    int value;

    Number(int value) { this.value = value; }

    void negate() { value = -value; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "value: " + value; }
}
```

**The main method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Number A = Number.ONE;
    A.negate();
    Number B = Number.ONE;

    System.out.println(A + "   " + B);
}
```

**Output:**

> value: -1   value: -1

So my question is, can the output ever be the following (if say `A = null;` is added before `B` is used)?

> value: -1   value: 1

Comment: Short answer "no". Long answer "noooooooo". Longer answer - if one of my developers came to me with a mutable `enum` then they would be kindly asked to rethink their code.

Comment: I was going to add "imagine someone is naughty enough to write a mutable enum" :) I agree that it is bad practice to use a mutable `enum`. Nevertheless...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums are implicitly `public static final` fields, so they are never garbage collected.

EDIT

As kindly pointed out in the comments by @RealSkeptic, things are a little bit more complex in a jvm instance with multiple class loaders. Then static field values may disapear when their [classes are unloaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7).

However, by default, there is only one class loader which is alive as long as the jvm instance is alive, so in your example application it can never happen that static fields are garbage collected.

Comment: They are not _effectively_ `public static final`. They **are**.

Comment: Okay, to clarify, `public static final` implies that the instance will sit there in memory forever, despite all references to it being lost?

Comment: Actually, that's not strictly guaranteed. If their class loader is garbage-collected, they may go with it.

Comment: @DustByte True, and it is `static` modifier of the three that will prevent the referenced data from being garbage collected. Once the class is loaded and initialized by the class loader, its static data exist for the entire lifespan of the class loader instance.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic No. It is only guaranteed to exist for the lifespan of the class loader. If you have a custom class loader that loaded them, then they [may be unloaded](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7).

Comment: @RealSkeptic True also. I just wanted to simplify the explanation, because there is only one class loader in the example application provided by the OP. I edited my comment anyway; thanks for the remark.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, better word is _implicitly_. I edited the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: I gather from above that under, should I say normal, circumstances, there is only one class loader, hence the static fields are never garbage collected. When would I have multiple class loaders? Perhaps this is a too wide topic to be discussed here. The concepts of class loaders and different JVMs are beyond my knowledge of Java.

Comment: Multiple class loaders are used by modern application servers for example. You can deploy multiple different applications to the same application servers instance so that they all run in the same jvm instance (the application server instance). But applications are independent from each other, and each has has its own class loader, although they share the same jvm instance, the same heap, etc. Technically, things are again more complex under the hood, because the app server may use multiple class loaders per single application to load app server modules that the app utilizes for example.

Comment: But, the point is the same. In the application server example, from the standpoint of your deployed application, the static fields (thus including enums) will not be unloaded/garbage collected until the application is undeployed or until the application server is shut down, meaning that static state is preserved for the entire lifespan of the deployed application.

Answer (score 4):

For this enum:

```
public enum FooEnum {
  CONST
}
```

This byte code is generated:

```
Compiled from "FooEnum.java"
public final class FooEnum extends java.lang.Enum<FooEnum> {
  public static final FooEnum CONST;

  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #1                  // class FooEnum
       3: dup
       4: ldc           #12                 // String CONST
       6: iconst_0
       7: invokespecial #13                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      10: putstatic     #17                 // Field CONST:LFooEnum;
      13: iconst_1
      14: anewarray     #1                  // class FooEnum
      17: dup
      18: iconst_0
      19: getstatic     #17                 // Field CONST:LFooEnum;
      22: aastore
      23: putstatic     #19                 // Field ENUM$VALUES:[LFooEnum;
      26: return

  public static FooEnum[] values();
    // elided

  public static FooEnum valueOf(java.lang.String);
    // elided
}
```

*CONST* is a final static variable whose lifetime is that of the class.

Enums will only be garbage collected if the class is garbage collected.

From The Java Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition section [8.9. Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> **An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants. It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly
>   instantiate an enum type (§15.9.1).**
>
> In addition to the compile-time error, three further mechanisms ensure
>   that no instances of an enum type exist beyond those defined by its
>   enum constants:
>
> The final clone method in Enum ensures that enum constants can never
>   be cloned.
>
> Reflective instantiation of enum types is prohibited.
>
> Special treatment by the serialization mechanism ensures that
>   duplicate instances are never created as a result of deserialization.